# Jenkinsfile does not take into account conditional on branch

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Here are the stages of my `Jenkinsfile`

```
  stages {
    
    stage("build") {
        when {
            expression {
                BRANCH_NAME = 'alerta_dev_infra'
            }
        }
        steps {
            echo 'buidling the webhook'
        }
    }

    stage("test") {
        when {
            expression {
                env.BRANCH_NAME = 'alerta*'
            }
        }
          steps {
              echo 'testing the webhook'
        }
    }

    stage("deploy") {
        when {
            expression {
                env.BRANCH_NAME = 'alerta_dev_infra'
            }
        }
          steps {
              echo 'deploying the webhook'
        }
    }

  }
```

However, when it is executed:

```
14:10:00  Push event to branch alerta_dev_infra
14:10:00  Started by user pkaramol@foo.bar
14:10:00  Rebuilds build #9

14:10:49  First time build. Skipping changelog.
14:10:49  [Pipeline] }
14:10:49  [Pipeline] // stage
14:10:49  [Pipeline] withEnv
14:10:49  [Pipeline] {
14:10:49  [Pipeline] container
14:10:49  [Pipeline] { (hide)
14:10:49  [Pipeline] stage
14:10:49  [Pipeline] { (build)
14:10:49  Stage "build" skipped due to when conditional
14:10:49  [Pipeline] }
14:10:50  [Pipeline] // stage
14:10:50  [Pipeline] stage
14:10:50  [Pipeline] { (test)
14:10:50  Stage "test" skipped due to when conditional
14:10:50  [Pipeline] }
14:10:50  [Pipeline] // stage
14:10:50  [Pipeline] stage
14:10:50  [Pipeline] { (deploy)
14:10:50  Stage "deploy" skipped due to when conditional
14:10:50  [Pipeline] }
14:10:50  [Pipeline] // stage
14:10:50  [Pipeline] }
14:10:50  [Pipeline] // container
14:10:50  [Pipeline] }
14:10:50  [Pipeline] // withEnv
14:10:50  [Pipeline] }
14:10:50  [Pipeline] // node
14:10:50  [Pipeline] }
14:10:50  [Pipeline] // podTemplate
14:10:50  [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Comment: I think you need the double equal == rather =

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
when {
                expression {
                    return env.GIT_BRANCH == "origin/master"
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Choice Parameter to provide three choices for branch to select: master, develop and feature-1
[image]

Here is the pipeline code to use when conditional on `BRANCH_NAME` parameter

```yaml
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage ('Build in master') {
            when {
                expression { params.BRANCH_NAME == 'master' }
            }
            
            steps {
                echo "Building in master"
            }
        }
        
        stage ('Build in develop')
        {
            when {
                expression { params.BRANCH_NAME == 'develop' }
            }
            
            steps {
                echo "Building in develop"
            }
        }
        
        stage ('Build in feature')
        {
            when {
                expression { params.BRANCH_NAME == 'feature-1' }
            }
            
            steps {
                echo "Building in feature-1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output of the pipeline job:
[image]